# Chrome Master_Preference AllowPopUps

Tags: chrome

Does anyone if there is a setting to a certain domain via the Master_Preferences file? I thought I had my json working, however, i'm getting an error with Content_Settings.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to create an exception via Master_Preference file, i'm just not having any luck.

Trying to weigh my options...use this, or GPO.

Thanks in advance,